# How can I show that $\overline{h(\mathbb{R})}^{S^2}=S^2$

Tags: general-topology

$S^2$ is the sphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$ space and $p^{-1}=h:\mathbb{R^2}\to S^2$ ($p$ is the stereographic projection) is an embedding. How can I show that $\overline{\mathbb{h(R^2)}}^{S^2}=S^2$?

I couldn't even find the image of the function; if I find the image, I think Ican do the rest.

Note: $p:S^2-(0,0,1)\to \mathbb{R^2}$

$(a,b,c)\to p(a,b,c)$ =$(\frac{a}{1-c},\frac{b}{1-c})$

Comment: Wouldn't the image of $h$ be $S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\}$?

Comment: Yes i guess. Because h is an injection. So can we say $\overline{\mathbb{h(R)}}^{S^2}=S^2$ because of the definition of usual topology?

Comment: I don't know if I'm being dumb but what exactly do you mean by $\overline{\mathbb{h(R)}}^{S^2}$? Do you just mean the closure of $h(\mathbb{R})$ in the topological space $S^2$?

Comment: What do you know about the stereographic projection?

Comment: I think $h(\Bbb R)$ doesn't make sense, as $\Bbb R$ isn't a subset of the domain of $h$.

Comment: Sorry not $h(\mathbb{R})$ it will be $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: @gpassante ah yeah didn't spot that. My question still stands though BERAT, does $\overline{h(\mathbb{R}^2)}^{S^2}$ mean the closure of $h(\mathbb{R}^2)$ in $S^2$?

Comment: Yes you understood what i asked. Sorry i didnt see that i was editing what i miss in the question

Comment: In this case, $\;\overline{h(\Bbb R^2)}^{\,S^2}=\overline{S^2-\{(0,0,1)\}}^{\,S^2}=S^2$.